# 'project.urls' Not be recognized in PyPi

Tags: setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

I have the following in my `setup.cfg` file:

```ini
[project.urls]
"Documentation" = "https://pysui.readthedocs.io"
"Bug Reports" = "https://github.com/FrankC01/pysui/issues"
```

My build executes without error and `twine check` and `twine upload` work without a hitch. However, the extra links do not show up in PyPi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that format works only with the `pyproject.toml` as described at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#configuring-metadata . Note, the above describes how it works when using pypa's `build` for building, other packaging tools use their own ways to define this information.

If you prefer to use `setup.cfg`, you could try adding the `project_urls` under [`[metadata]`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#metadata) like this:

```
[metadata]
project_urls = 
    Documentation = https://pysui.readthedocs.io
    Bug Reports = https://github.com/FrankC01/pysui/issues
```

One more tip: you can check the `PKG-INFO` file in the created tar archive to see that the information was added correctly:

```
Project-URL: Documentation, https://pysui.readthedocs.io
Project-URL: Bug Reports, https://github.com/FrankC01/pysui/issues
```

Comment: The `[metadata]` approach didn't work in `setup.cfg`. I'm going to be moving over to `pyproject.toml` and I will use the link information you provided. Thanks